# Exibir registro do bd por id em um modal foundation 5 (pop-up)

Tags: php, zurb-foundation

Os *frameworks* que estou utilizando são o Zurb Foundation 5 e o Codeigniter.

Como exibir em um *modal foundation* 5 informações do banco de dados por ID? Na verdade já realizei o procedimento, só que não consigo exibir o registro por ID.

Exibindo registros com o link Reveal Modal:

```
 <?php
    $query = $this->protocolo->get_all_protocolo()->result();
    foreach ($query as $linha):
        echo '<tr>';
        printf('<td class="text-center">%s</td>', $linha->id);
        printf('<td class="text-center">%s</td>', $linha->nome);
        printf('<td class="text-center">%s</td>', $linha->numerodocumento);
        printf('<td class="text-center">%s</td>', anchor("protocolo/gerenciar/$linha->id", 'Observação', 'data-reveal-id="firstModal"'));
        printf('<td class="text-center">%s</td>', anchor('#', 'Detalhes', 'class="addimg"'));
        printf('<td class="text-center">%s</td>', 'Status');                
        echo '</tr>';
    endforeach;
 ?>
```

Formulário:

```
 <?php
    $iduser = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $querys = $this->protocolo->get_byid($iduser)->row();
    echo '<div id="firstModal" class="reveal-modal small" data-reveal>';
    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<div class="small-8 columns">';
    echo form_open('#');
    echo form_fieldset('Observação');
    echo form_label('Protocolo');
    echo form_input(array('name' => 'protocolo', 'class' => 'five', 'disabled' => 'disabled'), set_value('protocolo', $querys->id));
    echo form_label('Observação');
    echo form_textarea(array('name' => 'texto', 'class' => 'five'));
    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<div class="small-2 columns">';
    echo form_submit(array('name' => 'cadastrar', 'class' => 'button radius small font'), 'Salvar dados');
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;';
    echo '</div>';
    break;
```

Dessa forma ele me apresenta um erro quando vou para a tela de gerenciar(locahost/sistema/protocolo/gerenciar):

> Fatal error: Call to a member function row() on a non-object.

Creio eu que esse erro seja por conta de que eu estou chamando um modal que possui um parâmetro, no caso o id do usuário. Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Andrew pela minha experiência o que está acontecendo é que o `get_byid($iduser)` está a retornar `false` ou `null`. Veja qual o resultado dessa função fazendo um `var_dump($this->protocolo->get_byid($iduser))` e veja o resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos analisar o erro:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function row() on a non-object.

O erro diz que `row()` está sendo chamado em um não-objeto, que seria o protocolo buscado por meio do método `$this->protocolo->get_byid($iduser)`. Das duas, uma:

- A variável `$iduser` não está sendo recebida no modal, ou
- A variável `$iduser` está sendo recebida, mas não existe um protocolo com esse número.

Além disso, tem o fato de que `$iduser` vem da URL, por meio da chamada `$this->uri->segment(3)`. Veja se de fato essa é a melhor maneira de pegar o valor do URI.

Comment: Fiz uma condição na variável $iduser e o erro saiu. Porém agora o modal aparece dois problema: primeiro, quando clico pela primeira vez no link a url protocolo/gerenciar/2 é chamada, no entando, o modal não aparece nesse primeiro click, só a partir do segundo. O segundo problema é, quando clico no mesmo link pela segunda vez para executar o modal, a url sempre permanece com o mesmo valor em outros links, por exemplo, se executo protocolo/gerenciar/2, quando clico em outro link protocolo/gerenciar/3, ele me exibir o anterior, em todos os links!